# javascript, gulp, watch, changed

Tags: javascript, gulp, watch, gulp-changed

I cannot get my head around this.
This is supposed to be a gulp task that is executed every time a watched file is modified. Can anyone explain why it is required to pipe the watched files through the `changed` plugin?

```
gulp.task('build-css', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.css)
  .pipe(changed(paths.output, {extension: '.css'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['serve'], function() { 
  gulp.watch(paths.css, ['build-css']); 
});
```

Disclaimer: this is not my code. Just trying to understand what is going on, in order to create my own custom watch task.

Comment: What it is doing is piping it to several methods like first change to .css file and put the converted file in the destination paths.output.

Comment: I'd assume it only generates files that have actually been changed instead of all files.

Comment: this is the gulp watch task. gulp.task('watch', ['serve'], function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.css, ['build-css']);
}); doesn't the watch task provide the details about the changed file?
why is it necesary to look for changed files, if the watch is providing this for us??? seems redundant\

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference between `gulp.watch()`, `gulp-changed` and `gulp-watch` seems to cause a lot of confusion, so here's my attempt at untangling the mess:

#### `gulp.watch()`

This is the only one of the three that is [part of `gulp` itself](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/ae1ef092e6e3853760224f1b7acf5876f81c03f0/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb) and not a plugin. This is important, because it means that unlike the other two it is not passed to the `pipe()` function of a gulp stream.

Instead it is usually called directly from inside a gulp task:

```
 gulp.task('build-css', function() { 
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
      .pipe(doSomethingHere())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
 }); 

 gulp.task('watch', function() { 
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.css', ['build-css']); 
 });
```

In the above `gulp.watch()` is used to listen for changes in `.css` files. As long as `gulp.watch()` is running any change to a `.css` file automatically results in the execution of the `build-css` task.

This is where the trouble starts. Notice how no information about which files where changed is passed to `build-css`? That means even if you change just a single `.css` file *all* of your `.css` files will pass through `doSomethingHere()` again. The `build-css` task has no clue which of them changed. This may be fine as long as you have only a hand full of files, but can slow down your build as the number of files grows.

That's where `gulp-changed` comes in.

#### `gulp-changed`

This [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed) was written to act as a filter stage in a gulp stream. Its purpose is to remove all those files from a stream that haven't changed since the last build. It does this by comparing the files in the source directory with the resulting files in the destination directory:

```
 gulp.task('build-css', function() { 
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
      .pipe(changed('dist/css'))  //compare with files in dist/css
      .pipe(doSomethingHere())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
 }); 

 gulp.task('watch', function() { 
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.css', ['build-css']); 
 });
```

In the above the `build-css` task is still called for every change of a `.css` file and all `.css` files are read in. However only those files *that were actually changed* now reach the expensive `doSomethingHere()` stage. The rest is filtered out by `gulp-changed`.

This approach has the benefit of speeding up `build-css` even if you're not watching for file changes. You can explicitly invoke `gulp build-css` on the command-line and only those files that have changed since the last invocation of `build-css` will be rebuilt.

#### `gulp-watch`

This [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) is an attempt to improve on the built-in `gulp.watch()`. While `gulp.watch()` uses [`gaze`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gaze) to listen for file changes, `gulp-watch` uses [`chokidar`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) which is generally considered to be the more mature of the two.

You can use `gulp-watch` to achieve the same effect as using `gulp.watch()` and `gulp-changed` in combination:

```
 gulp.task('watch-css', function() { 
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
      .pipe(watch('src/**/*.css'))
      .pipe(doSomethingHere())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
 });
```

This again watches all `.css` files for changes. But this time whenever a `.css` file is changed, that file (and *only* that file) is read in again and reemitted to the stream where it passes through `doSomethingHere()` on its way to the destination directory.

---

Note that this comparison paints all three of the alternatives in rather broad strokes and leaves out certain details and features (e.g. I haven't talked about the callback functions that you can pass to both `gulp.watch()` and `gulp-watch`), but I think this should be enough to get the major differences between the three across.