# gulp-changed isn't filtering out non-changed files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, gulp-changed

I'm attempting to use [gulp-changed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed) to prevent time consuming tasks occurring on unchanged files.  My gulpfile.js has it setup like so:

```
gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(changed("."))
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['> 5%'] }))  //support browsers with >5% market share
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

However each time I see everything is being ran:

```
[11:15:02] Starting 'min:js'...
[11:15:02] Starting 'min:css'...
[11:15:02] Finished 'min:css' after 79 ms
Process terminated with code 0.
[11:15:02] Finished 'min:js' after 121 ms
[11:15:02] Starting 'min'...
[11:15:02] Finished 'min' after 12 μs
```

Any reason [gulp-changed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed) isn't filtering these unchanged files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First off** you seem to misunderstand what it is that `gulp-changed` actually does. `gulp-changed` cannot prevent tasks from running. That means these two lines:

```
[11:15:02] Starting 'min:css'...
[11:15:02] Finished 'min:css' after 79 ms
```

will appear in gulp's log output *even if not a single CSS file has changed*. `gulp-changed` simply removes unchanged files from the stream, so that they don't reach later `pipe()` stages. The files are still processed up to the point where they reach `changed()`.

(Coincidentally I wrote an answer just yesterday that also deals with `gulp-changed` and contrasts its mode of operation with `gulp.watch()` and `gulp-watch`. [Might be of interest too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149563/javascript-gulp-watch-changed/36162027#36162027).)

**Secondly**, how does `gulp-changed` know if a file has changed? It compares the source files with the destination files. If the destination files are older than the source files, the source files must have changed.

For that to work, `gulp-changed` must be able to map from a source file to a destination file. However you have multiple source files and just one destination file (your concatenated file). That means you would have to provide a custom [`hasChanged` handler](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed/blob/master/readme.md#haschanged) to map from your source files to your destination file.

**Thirdly**, even if you did all that your task still couldn't possibly work the way you want it to. Since `gulp-changed` only let's those files through that have been changed, only those files will end up in your concatenated output file.

Say you want to concatenate `foo.css` and `bar.css` into `all.css`. This would work fine the first time. But if you then change `bar.css`, *only* `bar.css` will end up in `all.css`.

Since you always need all of your CSS files as input, you *cannot* use `gulp-changed` in combination with `gulp-concat`.

**That being said**, if you want to speed up your `min:css` task when it is called from `gulp.watch()` you can follow the [official Gulp.js incremental rebuilding recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/112a3e0f4edb287b1838a095a650ff0ea687a8a1/docs/recipes/incremental-builds-with-concatenate.md):

```
gulp.task("min:css", function () {
  return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
    .pipe(cached('cssCache'))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['> 5%'] }))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(remember('cssCache'))
    .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed answer, I particularly didn't realise the concat/changed issue